# .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': No such file or directory - getaddrinfo (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, getaddrinfo

I got this error when I tried to run: rake db:migrate, rake schema:load and rails s. The application I git cloned from Bitbucket is unusable and the client is unable to help.

I have reinstalled ruby and gemset and it didn't work. I have no idea how to fix this error. Please help. What is causing the error and where I can find information that might help me fixing it?

Errno::ENOENT

```
No such file or directory - getaddrinfo
```

Rails.root: /home/jacek/Programming/Rails/idea-academy
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
newrelic_rpm (3.3.3) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:22:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
newrelic_rpm (3.3.3) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
newrelic_rpm (3.3.3) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:21:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
copycopter_client (2.0.1) lib/copycopter_client/client.rb:49:in `block in download'
copycopter_client (2.0.1) lib/copycopter_client/client.rb:113:in `connect'
copycopter_client (2.0.1) lib/copycopter_client/client.rb:46:in `download'
copycopter_client (2.0.1) lib/copycopter_client/cache.rb:101:in `download'
copycopter_client (2.0.1) lib/copycopter_client/request_sync.rb:17:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.3.3) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.3.3) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:24:in `call'
sass (3.1.15) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
remotipart (1.0.2) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:30:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
rails-dev-tweaks (0.6.1) lib/rails_dev_tweaks/granular_autoload/middleware.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:52:in `block in call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `each'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/jacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: running gem install bundler didn't change anything :-(

Comment: this exception is a timeout issue connecting to some external site.  it appears like its newrelic from the stacktrace.  Can you disable newrelic and see if you still get it?  Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: yes, I’m behind firewall

Comment: Setting agent_enabled: false in newrelic.yml didn't fix the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very old thread but I think I've found what was wrong.

When you use **net/http** and try to instantiate a new object passing the URL string `http = Net::HTTP.new("http://127.0.0.1:4567")`, you'll get this error.

you have to instantiate using an URI object, just like:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:4567")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install all the gems it needs?

did you do bundle install?

`gem install bundler`

`bundle`

Comment: I suspect the problem lies with newrelic or copy_copter client. Am I right? I never seen problems like this in my life.

Comment: If you still suspect that, you can try commenting the gems out of the gemfile, rebundling and trying to start the server again. You might be able to find out if they are causing the problem, then you can focus on getting the server up with those gems installed.